# Commerce & PayPal - What does "Solution Type" mean?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, settings

Our site is using the Craft Commerce plugin, and within that we've enabled the PayPal Express gateway. However, there is a very cryptic dropdown menu on the gateway settings page...

[image: Solution Type]

So my question is, **what is the "Solution Type"?**

What does that even mean? And what is the difference between the "Sole" and "Mark" options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ignore the terminology, it really makes no sense. What it should say is this...

**Require customers to use a PayPal account?**

- **[Sole]** No, a PayPal account is optional. Customers can still choose to pay with a credit card instead.
- **[Mark]** Yes, a PayPal account will be required to complete a purchase.

---

Here's a screenshot of the [documentation...](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)

[image: SOLUTIONTYPE]

So why did PayPal decide to call this particular choice "Solution Type"?

And what do "Sole" and "Mark" actually mean?

[The world may never know.](https://youtu.be/2IA5Cv_5-g8?t=7s)